# Github Actions: How to store kubeconfig in github secrets

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, cicd, kubeconfig, github-secret

I have this kubeconfig file

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ***
    server: ***
  name: ***
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ***
    user: webhook
  name: *****
current-context: *****
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: webhook
  user:
    token: ${MY_APIKEY}
```

I am storing it in secret in github that is named `DEV_CLUSTER_KUBECONF`

I am also storing MY_APIKEY in GitHub secrets

Then I have this actions workflow file whose purpose is the write the content into a file and then populate it with a token coming form github actions.

```
name: wfl

on:
  push:
env:
  DEV_CLUSTER_KUBECONF: ${{ secrets.DEV_CLUSTER_KUBECONF }}

jobs:
  j1:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ....
    container:
      image: .....
    steps:
      - name: pull kubeconfig
        run: |
          mkdir kubeconf
          touch kubeconf.conf
          echo $DEV_CLUSTER_KUBECONF >> kubeconf/kubeconf.conf

      - name: envsub kube.conf
        run: |
          cat kubeconf/kubeconf.conf | envsubst > populated_kube.conf
        env:
          MY_APIKEY: ${{ secrets.MY_APIKEY }}
      - name: export KUBECONFIG path
        run: echo "KUBECONFIG=populated_kube.conf" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: kubectl
        run: kubectl get po
```

This is a simplified version of my work. I prefer to keep it three steps. I mean I want to store the kubeconfig with the api key placeholder separate from the api key in the github secrets.

However, right now it is not connecting to k8s.

I used to keep kubeconf/kubeconf.conf in the repo and after checkout, do the envsubt on that file and it was working. I am not sure why it is not working now. seems like `kubeconf/kubeconf.conf` is not correct but when I try to print it and debug it is showing *******.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly quote your variables. Consider what happens if I create a multiline environment variable:

```
MVAR='this
is
a
test'
```

And then try to echo it without using quotes:

```
$ echo $MYVAR
this is a test
```

Compare that to the result when using quotes:

```
$ echo "$MYVAR"
this
is
a
test
```

---

So you need to edit your action to read:

```
      - name: pull kubeconfig
        run: |
          mkdir kubeconf
          echo "$DEV_CLUSTER_KUBECONF" > kubeconf/kubeconf.conf
```

(I've removed an unnecessary `touch kubeconf.conf` here, because that wasn't creating the file in the correct path and wasn't necessary in any case.)

If that doesn't work, the first thing you should do is add a `cat kubeconf/kubeconf.conf` to your workflow so you can inspect the generated file.